# Awk 3 Spaces + 1 space or hyphen

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a rather large chart to parse. Each column is separated by either 4 spaces or by 3 spaces and a hyphen (since the numbers in the chart can be negative).

```
cat DATA.txt | awk "{ print match($0,/\s\s/) }"
```

does nothing but print a slew of 0's. I'm trying to understand AWK and when to escape, etc, but I'm not getting the hang of it. Help is appreciated.

One line:

```
1979  1   -0.176   -0.185   -0.412    0.069   -0.129    0.297   -2.132   -0.334   -0.019
1979  1   -0.176    0.185   -0.412    0.069   -0.129    0.297   -2.132   -0.334   -0.019
```

I would like to get just, say, the second column. I copied the line, but I'd like to see -0.185 and 0.185.

Comment: An example with expected output would be better.

Comment: I'd like to see -0.185 and 0.185.

Comment: why ? `-0.176` is the second column where this is preceeded by three spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You need to start by thinking about `bash` quoting, since it is bash which interprets the argument to awk which will be the awk program. Inside double-quoted strings, `bash` expands `$0` to the name of the bash executable (or current script); that's almost certainly not what you want, since it will not be a quoted string. In fact, you almost never want to use double quotes around the awk program argument, so you should get into the habit of writing `awk '...'`.

Also, `awk` regular expressions don't understand `\s` (although Gnu awk will handle that as an extension). And `match` returns the position of the match, which I don't think you care about either.

Since by default, `awk` considers any sequence of whitespace a field separator, you don't really need to play any games to get the fourth column. Just use `awk '{print $4}'`

Comment: That fixed it. I don't even need to use match(). Thanks!

Comment: Added some more info. Here, have some [bedtime reading](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Running-gawk)

Comment: Plus one. I think the final word needs to be: NEVER write AWK inside of double quotation marks. ALWAYS use single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use this simple `awk`

```
awk '$0=$4' Data.txt
-0.185
0.185
```

It sets `$0` to value in `$4` and does the default action, print.
PS do not use `cat` with program that can read data itself, like `awk`

In case of filed `4` containing `0`, you can make it more robust like:

```
awk '{$0=$4}1' Data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to split the input according to 3 or 4 spaces   then you will get the expected output only from column 3.

```
$ awk -v FS=" {3,4}" '{print $3}' file
-0.185
0.185
```

`FS=" {3,4}"` here we pass a regex as FS value. This regex get parsed and set the Field Separator value to three or  four spaces. In regex `{min,max}` called range quantifier which repeats the previous token from min to max times.

Comment: I did not downvote, but consider what happens with `echo 'one         two' | awk '{print $2}'` with multiple spaces between 'one' and 'two' Qualifying the number of spaces is not awk like...